# When using packages, no class that depends on another can be found, even in the same folder

Tags: java, package

I'm struggling a lot to create packages. I've tried to follow three or four different resources on it, plus a handful of SO threads and couldn't find a clear definition of what goes where or why things aren't found at all. I've put all files from packages in their correspondent folders and also tried to let them in the root folder, to no avail. I can just compile classes that don't depend at all on other classes thus far whenever I use the `package` keyword to package them.

This would be one of my packages:

- `StateMachine`
- `Facility` extends `StateMachine`
- `FacilityAI` (interface)
- `FacilityBehavior` extends `StateMachine` implements `FacilityAI`
- `Control` extends `StateMachine`
- `TimeController`

Example #1:

The most loosely coupled one in here is `TimeController`, I can compile this one without a problem from the root folder of the project by usying `javac -d . TimeController.java`. It creates a folder `marsmission`, and then `HabControl` inside that, and places the `class` file inside `HabControl`.

Now, `StateMachine` uses `Facility` to set states in the `Facility` objects. But when I try to compile from the root folder, I get a `cannot find symbol` error pointing to `Facility`. An error that didn't exist prior me trying to put them on packages.

Example #2:

I have the dataaccess folder with my files inside it, `WriteFile`, and `ReadFile`, since the latter just reads external files, it compiles without a problem with `javac -d . ReadFile.java`, but `WriteFile`, using the same method, can't find `FacilityMachines`, `Facility`, and the states that belong to `StateMachine`. I've tried using `import marsmission.habcontrol.Facility;`, `import marsmission.habcontrol.*;`, and `import marsmission.habcontrol;` to no avail.

How do I solve this?

Edit:

For Example #2, I had just assumed that when I compiled `StateMachine`, all of its dependencies had compiled as well. So I just had to compile them, and then it just worked. I also had to make a few changes to constructors that weren't declared nor `public`, nor `private`, and had no idea that if they are just declared without defined access they were instantly made `private`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Have you imported the newly added classes along with package names wherever required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your root directory you have the subdir marsmission and inside that the subdir HabControl.
Inside HabControl reside your Java files TimeController.java, StateMachine.java, etc. 
All these Java files have a package declaration like this:

```
package marsmission.HabControl;
```

Then go with your command line into the root directory and type:

```
javac -d . marsmission/HabControl/TimeController.java
```

After that, there is a classfile TimeController.class in the same directory as TimeController.java.

Then

```
javac -d . marsmission/HabControl/StateMachine.java
```

This will find the other class files or even compile all the dependend Java files.

After you learnt how things work with `javac` you should consider to use a build tool like Ant, Maven or Gradle.

Additionally, by convention, package names in Java are all lower case.